# How can I identify missing documents in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

**Background**:

In my ElasticSearch index, I have two types of documents that can be identified as 'bvi_ship' and 'bvi_notify'. Each document that is identified as 'bvi_ship' should also have a corresponding document identified as 'bvi_notify'.

**Question**:

What is an appropriate way of identifying the 'bvi_ship' documents that don't have a 'bvi_notify' document?

**Using Facet**:

I've been able to identify the necessary documents using the following faceted code:

```
{
   "size":0,
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
         "query":{
            "query_string":{
               "default_operator":"OR",
               "default_field":"_all",
               "query":"@fields.action:\"bv_ship\" OR @fields.action:\"bvi_notify\""
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "facets":{
      "terms":{
         "terms":{
            "field":[
               "@fields.object"
            ],
            "size":1000
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Which returns results that look like this:

```
{
  "took" : 147,
  ...
  },
  "hits" : {
    ...
  },
  "facets" : {
    "terms" : {
      ...
      "terms" : [ {
        "term" : "xml",
        "count" : 1443
      }, {
        "term" : "content_ff47d2d096ea4510ac0895941666e507",
        "count" : 2
      }, {
        "term" : "content_fa525becb2724b7682df278c02fed308",
        "count" : 2
      },
        ... THOUSANDS OF RECORDS WITH COUNT of 2
      }, {
        "term" : "content_f1ff2f7440534a08bad4c62b92165949",
        "count" : 1
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

This *could* work well, but I obviously don't want to return thousands of records that have a count of 2 when I am really only interested in the records that have a count of 1.

Is there a way to limit the faceted search so that it only returns the records with a count of 1?

**Using Filter**:

I'm guessing I should be able to be more specific in my query and simply select the appropriate records using a combination of Queries and Filters, though my ElasticSearch Kung-Fu is being handicapped by my Relational Database Karate.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is to index records with 'bvi_notify' objects as children of records with 'bvi_ship' objects. Then you will be able to use [has_child](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/has-child-filter/) filter in `must_not` clause of a `bool` filter to find all 'bvi_ship' documents that don't have corresponding 'bvi_notify' objects.

To answer your original question, there is no way to limit term facets to only terms with a count of 1, but you can sort facets using `reverse_count` order, which will bring all terms with count of 1 to the top of the list. However, I should also mention that if you have more than 1 shard, the counts that you get in your facets [might be incorrect](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/1305). This is another reason why I would recommend going with parent/child solution instead of facets.

Comment: I had thought about the parent/child relationship, unfortunately I don't have direct control of how documents are indexed beyond supplying basic parameters. Thanks for the idea about reverse_count and and the heads up on why they may be incorrect.